# How do you express a "null" value in Go?

Tags: go

How do you express a "null" value in Go?

```
type Node struct { 
    next *Node
    data interface{}
}
```

And I want to say

```
return &Node{ data: NULL, next: NULL }
```

Answer (score 143, accepted):

The equivalent of `NULL` is `nil`, as you already discovered. Note, though, that you don't generally need to initialize things to `nil` or zero in Go, because by default all variables (including dynamically allocated ones) are set to “zero values” according to type (numbers zero, references `nil`). So in your example saying `new(Node)` would result in a Node with both fields `nil`.

Comment: Why the most trivial things are different null/nil int i=0/i int =0

Comment: @Barelelbaz Different than what? =) I mean, Go is its own language, it should do what is right in the big picture of Go, not try to make things deceptively similar to some other language. The NULL vs nil is a fairly minor cosmetic thing, but the `int i` vs `i int` is a major change with many readability improvements in complex cases. (And I say this with all fondness and respect toward C, which I've been programming in since the mid 90's, but it does not set the gold standard for good syntax.)

Comment: Got it, agreed.

Answer (score 26):

I just found out is `nil`